# Cached variable remains after truncating cache table

Tags: 7, caching

I updated a row in the `variables` table to change the value of a variable. Then I truncated the `cache` table. But a call to variable_get() still returns the original value.

I thought that the variables were cached in the `cache` table, so where could this original value be hiding?

EDIT: I waited a few minutes and tried again and it was OK. So the immediate problem is solved, but I would like to understand what happened. Is there another layer of caching? It seems there must be since it could not have gotten that value by querying either `cache` (empty) or `variable` (containing new value).

Comment: variable_set and variable_del exist for a reason, try to use them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - the call to `variable_get()` was during the bootstrap process, so `cache_bootstrap` table also needed to be truncated.